# How to create a dynamic number of tasks taking into account the result of previous task in same DAG?

Tags: python, dataframe, airflow

I want to create a dynamic number of tasks taking into account the number of chunks obtained when I read a CSV in the previous task. Add to that, I wanna to run all the dynamic tasks at same time and after all finished run the final task. All this inside the same DAG.

To make the "image" more clear I created a diagram:

[image]

And the code:

```
#python imports
import awswrangler as wr
import boto3
from datetime import datetime
#airflow imports
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

# First PythonOperator
def read_csv(s3_dir,client_s3,**kwargs):
    
    df_list = wr.s3.read_csv(s3_dir, sep='|', chunksize = 100,boto3_session = client_s3)
    
    intermediate_dir = Variable.get("s3_intermediate_dir")
    
    for idx, df in enumerate(df_list):
        wr.s3.to_csv(df,intermediate_dir + "intermediate_{}".format(idx))
    
    ti.xcom_push(key='number_of_chunks', value=len(df_list))

# * PythonOperator
def transform_dataframes(s3_dir,client_s3,**kwargs):
    #DO SOMETHING
    
# Final PythonOperator
def agg_df_one(s3_dir,client_s3,**kwargs):
    #list all files
    all_files = wr.s3.list_objects(s3_dir, boto3_session = client_s3)
    #agg_df_one
    df_list = [wr.s3.read_csv(file, sep='|', chunksize = 100,boto3_session = client_s3) for file in all_files]

    final_df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    now = datetime.now()
    dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y-%H")
    
    #save final s3
    final_dir = Variable.get("s3_final_dir")
    wr.s3.to_csv(final_df,final_dir + dt_string + "/final_df.csv")    
    
    #delete all
    wr.s3.delete_objects(all_files,boto3_session = client_s3)
    
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': True,
    'wait_for_downstream': True,
    'retries': 0,
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='test_parallelism_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='@hourly',
    catchup=False,
    max_active_runs=3,
    oncurrency = 10,
)

client_s3 = boto3.session(aws_access_key_id  = Variable.get("s3_key_id"),aws_secret_access_key = Variable.get("s3_secret_key")) 

wr.s3.endpoint = Variable.get("s3_endpoint_url")

read_csv_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='read_csv_func',
    python_callable=read_csv,
    provide_context=True,
    op_kwargs={'s3_dir':Variable.get("init_s3_dir",'client_s3':client_s3},
    dag=dag
)

transform_dataframes_task = [PythonOperator(
    task_id=f'test_parallelism_dag.transform_dataframe_chunk_{i}',
    python_callable=transform_dataframes,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag
) for i in "{{ ti.xcom_pull(key='number_of_chunks') }}"]


agg_df_one_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='agg_df_one_func',
    python_callable=agg_df_one,
    provide_context=True,
    trigger_rule = 'none_failed',
    dag=dag
)

read_csv_task >> transform_dataframes_task >> agg_df_one_task
```

My question here, How can I pass the size of list of chunks to the task "transform_dataframes_task " in order to create all needed tasks?

Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible today but will be possible soon.

We just approved an AIP in Apache Airflow (Airflow Improvement Proposal) that will enable this pattern  - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-42%3A+Dynamic+Task+Mapping and it is very likely to get implemented in Airflow 2.3.

Comment: Hmm, so if I was processing partitioned parquet data then I could generate a task per partition? This was something I dreamed of long ago, nice. I wonder how the performance would be versus running the task using a script that uses Dask to read the same data (so one task and then Dask handles the parallelization).

Comment: I do not know Dask performance characteristic well enough, but with modern approach such us custom decorators, we will be able to achieve very interesting optimisations without sacrificing readability of Dags. For example it should be possible to tap into Dask's partitioning and not really "run" any processing in Airlfow but create a mirror task for each of the Dask partition in Airflow DAG. So that you could still execute all partitioning and processing in Dask but see them as separate tasks in Airflow

Comment: So rather than "Either Airflow or Dask" it will be "more seamless integration of Dask workflows with Airflow"

Comment: Very cool, thank you